# Perform operation on dataframe values based on another file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file like this with a bunch of values -

```
Time,metric_A,metric_B,metric_C
0,1,2,3
1,3,4,5
2,7,8,9
```

I can easily read this as a dataframe and compute new metrics like metric_A+metric_B like

```
df=pandas.read_csv('file.csv)
df['new_metric']=df['metric_A']+df['metric_B']
```

here is where tricky part comes in. Rather than defining each new metric indiviually I want to import a file with some formulas such as below. I want to add these new metrics to the original csv file as well

```
formula File - sample
new_metric_A=metric_A/metric_B
new_metric_B=metric_A-metric_B
new_metric_D=metric_A/(metric_B+metric_C)
```

Final expected output be something like -

```
Time,metric_A,metric_B,metric_C,new_metric_A,new_metric_B,new_metric_D
0,1,2,3,X,Y
1,3,4,5,A,B
2,7,8,9,C,D
```

How do I do this ? I initially thought about using regular expressions but that quicky became nasty so I starting thinking about other ways. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make you input like a dict , then we call eval

```
d={'new_metric_A':'metric_A/metric_B',
'new_metric_B':'metric_A-metric_B',
'new_metric_D':'metric_A/(metric_B+metric_C)'}
for x , y in d.items():
    df[x]=df.eval(y)

df
   Time  metric_A  metric_B  metric_C  new_metric_A  new_metric_B  new_metric_D
0     0         1         2         3         0.500            -1      0.200000
1     1         3         4         5         0.750            -1      0.333333
2     2         7         8         9         0.875            -1      0.411765
```